# Выборка строк с пустым полем из таблицы в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следующее: есть поле в таблице типа `varchar(50)` -  нужно вывести все строки, где это поле пустое.

Пробовал делать что-то типа `IS NULL`, но не помогает; пробовал `ПОЛЕ=''`, но тоже самое.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: where pole is null or pole = '' or length(pole)=0

Comment: Если is null и поле='' не помагает, значит у вас поле не пустое. Может там пробелы стоят или ещё что... Стоит выяснить что там в этом поле и использовать соответствующее условие.

Comment: Не кидайте в меня кирпичами, но я бы автору-новичку посоветовал бы использовать (изредка) GUI, типа HEIDI SQL, чтобы визуально создавать фильтры. Тем самым, видя правильный результат, автор видел бы и запоминал бы синтаксис SQL, который был сгенерирован для реализации фильтра.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я пробовал что-то типа where pole is null or pole = '' or length(pole)=0 но не помогло, потом сделал выборку по другому тоже пустому полю и тогда заработало, всё равно большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может не получается, потому что поле содержит пробельные символы?
Попробуйте что-нибудь типа where field is null or trim(field)=''

Comment: Спасибо, думаю вы правы. Все ответы пригодились, большое всем спасибо!)